# Rendering SVGs using Renderer2 in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-renderer2

How do I render an `SVG` (which I have locally stored in my project) using Renderer2 in Angular?

I tried doing it like following:

```
const div = this.renderer.createElement('div');
const svg = this.renderer.createText('<svg>{....}</svg>');
this.renderer.appendChild(div, svg);
```

But it actually got renderer as a text.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `createText` method is used to create a [text node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text), in this case you can set innerHTML directly.

```js
const div = this.renderer.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = svgStr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you can create a svg with a selected path using a simple variable and `[attr.d]="variable` in a path, e.g.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" 
      fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path [attr.d]="path"/>
</svg>
```

And in .ts:

```
path="M14 16a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2H2a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12zM5.904 5.197 10 9.293V6.525a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0V10.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5H6.525a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h2.768L5.197 5.904a.5.5 0 0 1 .707-.707z"
```